# XMLSearch and display node info

Tags: xml, coldfusion

I'm trying to display the XML node data returned from XMLSearch and am having a problem displaying the data. I tried outputting the data like this:

```
<cfset xmlBeatles=XMLParse(ExpandPath("Beatles.xml"))>
<cfset Qdata = XMLsearch(xmlBeatles,"//beatle[1]")>

#Qdata.beatle.firstname.xmltext# or #Qdata[1].beatle.firstname.xmltext#
```

but am getting this error:

> You have attempted to dereference a scalar variable of type class
>   coldfusion.runtime.Array as a structure with members.

**Sample XML:**

[image: Screenshot of XML dump]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to extract the data by doing this `Qdata[1].name.firstname.xmltext`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing the "name" element. Try "Qdata.beatle.name.firstname.xmltext" to see if that works.

Comment: Thanks for your response Paul. Sadly this "Qdata.beatle.name.firstname.xmltext" didn't work. I got this error "You have attempted to dereference a scalar variable of type class coldfusion.runtime.Array as a structure with members." Any suggestion?